# Xtst and usleep

Tags: linux, xlib

I'm using the Xtst extentsion to type and do stuff using the mouse
I have not encoutnered any problems untill I started using xtst to move and click the mouse.

for example, here's a set of action:
move 359,216 & click  (XTestFakeMotionEvent(display,-1,359,216,0);)
move 378,213 & click
move 376,391 & click
type amousa1990@gmail.com, adel_ahmed@something.com  (the string is broken down into characters and then           XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode, True, 0);   this code has been working fine for the past couple of months, til I started using mouse movements and clicks
move 438,727 & click

plenty of other clicks

what happens is all mouse movements work fine, the typing events are not sent/synced
unless I use usleep of:
100 before each letter typed
500 before each click
700000 before each mouse movements

mouse movement usleeps are slowing down the app severely 
the code is as follows for mouse movement:

```
XFlush(display);
usleep(700000);
XTestFakeMotionEvent(display,-1,x_coordinate,y_coordinate,0);

XFlush(display);
  XCloseDisplay(display);
```

should I keep the display open and use a pointer instead(I'm calling these functions within a function)
should I flush more/less often

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think keyboard Auto repeat settings in your desktop environment, may have an impact on the behaviour of the program